# Docker cgroup.procs no space left on device

Tags: linux, docker

After some problem with Docker and my dedicated server with a Debian (the provider give some OS image without some features needed by Docker, so I recompiled Linux kernel yesterday and activate the features needed, I followed some instruction in blog).

Now I was happy to have success with docker I tried to create image... and I have an error.

```
$ docker run -d -t -i phusion/baseimage /sbin/my_init -- bash -l
Unable to find image 'phusion/baseimage:latest' locally
Pulling repository phusion/baseimage
5a14c1498ff4: Download complete 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
53f858aaaf03: Download complete 
837339b91538: Download complete 
615c102e2290: Download complete 
b39b81afc8ca: Download complete 
8254ff58b098: Download complete 
ec5f59360a64: Download complete 
2ce4ac388730: Download complete 
2eccda511755: Download complete 
Status: Downloaded newer image for phusion/baseimage:latest
0bd93f0053140645a930a3411972d8ea9a35385ac9fafd94012c9841562beea8
FATA[0039] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 0bd93f0053140645a930a3411972d8ea9a35385ac9fafd94012c9841562beea8: [8] System error: write /sys/fs/cgroup/docker/0bd93f0053140645a930a3411972d8ea9a35385ac9fafd94012c9841562beea8/cgroup.procs: no space left on device
```

More informations :

```
$ docker info
Containers: 3
Images: 12
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:1-275423-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 814.4 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 12.22 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 1.413 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.146 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: false
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.82-git (2013-10-04)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.19.0-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.691 GiB
Name: ns3289160.ip-5-135-180.eu
ID: JK54:ZD2Q:F75Q:MBD6:7MPA:NGL6:75EP:MLAN:UYVU:QIPI:BTDP:YA2Z
```

System :

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           788M  456K  788M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        20G  7.8G   11G  43% /
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.7G  4.0K  1.7G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2       898G   11G  842G   2% /home
```

Edit: command `du -sk /var`

```
# du -sk /var
3927624 /var
```

Edit: command `fdisk -l`

```
# fdisk -l
```

Disk /dev/loop0:

```
100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop1: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00060a5c

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          4096   40962047   40957952  19.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         40962048 1952471039 1911508992 911.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       1952471040 1953517567    1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/mapper/docker-8:1-275423-pool: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 byte
```

Comment: it would help to see the output from `du -sk /var` and `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I update my first post with the results of your command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed docker via `docker-lxc` in the debian repos, I followed a tuto. I tried another solution (with success), I updated my source.list `/etc/apt/source.list` from **jessie** to **sid**, I removed `docker-lxc` with a purge and I installed `docker.io`.
The error changed. It was `mkdir -p /sys/... can't create dir : access denied`
So I find a comment in a blog and I tried the solution it was to comment this line previously added by the tutorial :

```
 ## file /etc/fstab
 # cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup defaults 0 0
```

and reboot the server.

Comment: Hi, Can you point to the doc that talks about modifying the /etc/fstab?

Comment: Removing cgroup from fstab fixes the same problem for me, too. Though I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

You should not remove cgroup support in docker. Otherwise you may get warning like `WARNING: Your kernel does not support memory swappiness capabilities, memory swappiness discarded.` when you run a docker container.

A simple command should do the trick.

```
sudo echo 1 > /sys/fs/cgroup/docker/cgroup.clone_children
```

If it still does not work, run below commands and restart docker service:

```
sudo echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/docker/cpuset.mems
sudo echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/docker/cpuset.cpus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install -y libcgroup libcgroup-devel libcgroup-tools

cgclear
service cgconfig restart

mount -t cgroup none /cgroup

vi /etc/fstab
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup defaults 0 0
```